# How to format results of Get-ChildItem in depth-first?

Tags: powershell

The Get-ChildItem function in PowerShell by default outputs in breadth-first. Is it possible to make it output as depth-first?

Look, it outputs breadth-first!

```
PS C:\dev\stack-overflow-question> Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object FullName

FullName
--------
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\foo
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\quz
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\my.csv
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\special-tree.ps1
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\foo\bar
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\foo\bar\baz
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\foo\bar\baz\hw.txt
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\quz\empty-dir
```

Ugh! So hard to read! But instead, I want it to be depth-first! Something like this. Is there some way to do this?

```
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\my.csv
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\special-tree.ps1
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\foo
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\foo\bar
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\foo\bar\baz
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\foo\bar\baz\hw.txt
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\quz
C:\dev\stack-overflow-question\quz\empty-dir
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to either re-sort `Get-ChildItem` output or re-write its logic to traverse directories to get the output you desire. I prefer rewriting it personally, more efficient that way. You might find also interesting what [PSTree](https://github.com/santisq/PSTree) has to offer.

A few points to consider:

1. This method outputs the initial path, this can be avoided using `Select-Object -Skip 1`.
2. **In Unix like platforms**, the alphabetical ordering of files might not be ensured, you can however use `$files | Sort-Object Name`.
3. `.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()` outputs all directory children, including **Hidden and System**, you can however add an `if` condition to skip items meeting the condition `.Attributes.HasFlag([System.IO.FileAttributes] 'Hidden, System')`.

```bash
$stack = [System.Collections.Generic.Stack[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]]::new()
# Change `$pwd.Path` for an absolute path to a Folder
$stack.Push($pwd.Path)
& {
    while ($stack.Count) {
        $target = $stack.Pop()

        try {
            $enum = $target.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning $_
            $target
            continue
        }

        $files = foreach ($item in $enum) {
            if ($item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
                $stack.Push($item)
                continue
            }
            $item
        }

        $target
        $files
    }
} | Select-Object FullName
```